# Select only the YEAR from DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some queries like below:

```
Insert into Employee_T (EmployeeID,
                        EmployeeName,
                        EmployeeAddress,
                        EmployeeCity,
                        EmployeeState,
                        EmployeeZip,
                        EmployeeDateHired,
                        EmployeeBirthDate,
                        EmployeeSupervisor) 
values ('123-44-345',
        'Phil Morris',
        '2134 Hilltop Rd',
        'Knoxville',
        'TN',
        null,
        to_timestamp('12-JUN-99','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),
        to_timestamp('05-JAN-57','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),
        '454-56-768');
```

I have a homework question asking "Which employees were hired during 1999?" the bold date above.

How do write a select statement for selecting year only, and ignore day and month?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_T
WHERE EMPLOYEEDATEHIRED = '***what should i put here?***';
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: try `WHERE YEAR( EMPLOYEEDATEHIRED) = 1999`

Comment: oracle. year function does not work

Comment: @SpencerLin When providing additional clarification, do so in your Question rather than in comments. Click the `edit` link found beneath your Question (if in a web browser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_T WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM EmployeeDateHired) = 1999
```

Comment: @SpencerLin can you please mark it as an answer if it answers your question?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## `EXTRACT`

As required by the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) specifications, [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) offer the [`EXTRACT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function. You pass a selector such as `YEAR` or `MONTH` to retrieve that aspect of a date-time value.

```
SELECT EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' ) ;
```

Result:

```
2001
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a calculation like `EXTRACT` on a column the optimizer will loose the opportunity to utilize an existing index.

To get a "Searchable ARGument" you better use the column as-is:

```
WHERE EmployeeDateHired >= TIMESTAMP '1999-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND EmployeeDateHired <  TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

In Oracle you might also use DATE which automatically adds `00:00:00`:

```
WHERE EmployeeDateHired >= DATE '1999-01-01'
  AND EmployeeDateHired <  DATE '2000-01-01'
```